# Prove that the result of linear function is the intersection of all permutation

Tags: linear-algebra, permutations, computational-mathematics

It is a long story I just make it short. First I will star with permutation. 
Let $S$ denote the group of all possible permutations of $C$. Let $A$ be the subset of all acceptable permutation for $C$, where $A  \subset S$. $A$ is said to be t-intersecting if all permutation in $A$, lets call it $s_n$, $s_n$ $\in$ $A$  agree on at least t points, where $ \mid t \mid \leq H$. $H$ can be any number.
 It is natural to ask, how small, and large can an intersecting in $A$? An example of a small intersecting of permutations is when the number of intersection is the lower bound  $ \mid t \mid < H$ of the hidden comments.  An example of a large intersecting is when $ \mid t \mid = H$.

let's say H is the value of the intersection. For example, if H=3, then the lower bond of the intersection is 1, and the upper bound is 3. Now, t is the intersection of all permutation in A and bounded by the lower and upper bound of H. In this example, if t=1, it means, there is one common element in all permutation of A,  $ \mid t \mid < H$ . Assume, there is a linear function that gives the same result of t. I mean, if the intersection shows there is one common element in all permutation of A, then linear function also shows the same number of common element. How we can prove that the linear function gives the intersection result?

Comment: What is $C$?  An arbitrary set?  A finite set?

Comment: @RobertShore C is an arbitrary set, and finite. A is the subset of S, which contains some specific permutation and finite. It's not important how permutations of $A$ have selected.

Comment: I can't discern the purpose of $|t|\leq H.$  Perhaps do you mean $|A| \leq H$?  That is, so that $H = (|C|-t)!$ ... I also can't discern what you mean by "imagine there is a linear function which gives the same result of intersection. How we can prove that the result of the intersection and linear function is the same."  What is the "result of intersection", and what does it mean for the linear function to give the same result?

Comment: @BrianMoehring let's say H is the value of the intersection result. For example, if H=3, then the lower bond of the intersection is 1, and the upper bound is 3.  Now, t is the intersection of all permutation in A and bounded by the lower and upper bound of H. In this example, if t=1, it means, there is one common element in all permutation of A. Assume, there is a linear function that gives the same result of t. I mean, if the intersection shows there is one common element in all permutation of A, then linear function also shows the same number of common element.